# Parse the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the dataframe something like below in csv format:

```
Country  Status  People_eligible_Count
XYZ      True    100000
XYZ      False   14000
XYZ      Not Ap  360000
```

I want to turn the above dataframe to below format:

```
Country   True    False  Not Ap
XYZ       100000  14000  36000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pivot the table:

```
result = df.pivot('Country', 'Status')
result.columns = result.columns.levels[1] # Remove unnecessary column header
result.columns.name = '' # Optional
result.reset_index()
#  Country  False  Not Ap    True
#0 XYZ  14000  360000  100000
```

Comment: You can use ```.reset_index()``` in 1st line itself

Comment: @Hello.World What's the difference? Still the same number of operations.

Comment: Yes true. I am not saying that your solution is wrong :). I myself upvoted it. It was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid additional line for reset.index() like this:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'Count', index=['Country'], columns= 'Status').reset_index()
```